# Erro 400: invalid_request ao usar Python para enviar email pelo Gmail usando Oauth 2.0

Tags: python, oauth2, gmail

Eu utilizo scripts em Python para enviar email pela conta do Gmail. Antes bastava utilizar usuário e senha da conta do Gmail e configurar a conta do Gmail para permitir acesso a "apps menos seguros". Acontece que o Google vai desabilitar o uso de apps menos seguros a partir de 30/05/2022 e recomenda o uso de autenticação com OAuth 2.0.
Fiz o que recomenda este link:
https://blog.macuyiko.com/post/2016/how-to-send-html-mails-with-oauth2-and-gmail-in-python.html
e funcionou de boa por uma semana. Depois disso o token_refresh expirou e ao ler a documentação do OAuth, descobri que app's não verificados pelo Google e que estão em modo de "TESTE" o token_refresh expira em 7 dias. Então publiquei o "app", depois disso tentei refazer o procedimento pra gerar um novo token_refresh, mas agora apresenta a mensagem que o app não foi verificado pelo google. Li a documentação várias vezes e meu "app" que na verdade é só um script para enviar email, se encaixa na categoria de apps que não precisam de verificação, no entanto sempre que tento me deparo com a mensagem de alerta no navegador que diz:

**Erro de autorização
Erro 400: invalid_request
Não é possível fazer login no app porque ele não obedece à política de proteção de apps do OAuth 2.0 do Google.
Você pode informar ao desenvolvedor que o app não obedece a uma ou mais regras de validação do Google.**

Já tentei reconfigurar a tela de consentimento do Oauth, mas cai no mesmo problema.
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz eu agradeço.

Segue o código que eu uso, para testar, retirei do blog que eu coloquei o link nesse post.

```
insira o código aqui
```

"""
Adapted from:
https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/python/oauth2.py
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

1. Generate and authorize an OAuth2 (generate_oauth2_token)
2. Generate a new access tokens using a refresh token(refresh_token)
3. Generate an OAuth2 string to use for login (access_token)
   """

import base64
import imaplib
import json
import smtplib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import lxml.html

GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = ''
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = ''
GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN = None

def command_to_url(command):
return '%s/%s' % (GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL, command)

def url_escape(text):
return urllib.parse.quote(text, safe='~-._')

def url_unescape(text):
return urllib.parse.unquote(text)

def url_format_params(params):
param_fragments = []
for param in sorted(params.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
param_fragments.append('%s=%s' % (param[0], url_escape(param[1])))
return '&'.join(param_fragments)

def generate_permission_url(client_id, scope='https://mail.google.com/'):
params = {}
params['client_id'] = client_id
params['redirect_uri'] = REDIRECT_URI
params['scope'] = scope
params['response_type'] = 'code'
return '%s?%s' % (command_to_url('o/oauth2/auth'), url_format_params(params))

def call_authorize_tokens(client_id, client_secret, authorization_code):
params = {}
params['client_id'] = client_id
params['client_secret'] = client_secret
params['code'] = authorization_code
params['redirect_uri'] = REDIRECT_URI
params['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code'
request_url = command_to_url('o/oauth2/token')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8')).read().decode('UTF-8')
return json.loads(response)

def call_refresh_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
params = {}
params['client_id'] = client_id
params['client_secret'] = client_secret
params['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
params['grant_type'] = 'refresh_token'
request_url = command_to_url('o/oauth2/token')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8')).read().decode('UTF-8')
return json.loads(response)

def generate_oauth2_string(username, access_token, as_base64=False):
auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
if as_base64:
auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
return auth_string

def test_imap(user, auth_string):
imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap_conn.debug = 4
imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
imap_conn.select('INBOX')

def test_smpt(user, base64_auth_string):
smtp_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_conn.set_debuglevel(True)
smtp_conn.ehlo('test')
smtp_conn.starttls()
smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64_auth_string)

def get_authorization(google_client_id, google_client_secret):
scope = "https://mail.google.com/"
print('Navigate to the following URL to auth:', generate_permission_url(google_client_id, scope))
authorization_code = input('Enter verification code: ')
response = call_authorize_tokens(google_client_id, google_client_secret, authorization_code)
return response['refresh_token'], response['access_token'], response['expires_in']

def refresh_authorization(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token):
response = call_refresh_token(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token)
return response['access_token'], response['expires_in']

def send_mail(fromaddr, toaddr, subject, message):
access_token, expires_in = refresh_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
auth_string = generate_oauth2_string(fromaddr, access_token, as_base64=True)

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msg_alternative)
part_text = MIMEText(lxml.html.fromstring(message).text_content().encode('utf-8'), 'plain', _charset='utf-8')
part_html = MIMEText(message.encode('utf-8'), 'html', _charset='utf-8')
msg_alternative.attach(part_text)
msg_alternative.attach(part_html)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
server.starttls()
server.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + auth_string)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
if GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN is None:
print('No refresh token found, obtaining one')
refresh_token, access_token, expires_in = get_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
print('Set the following as your GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN:', refresh_token)
exit()

```
send_mail('..........@gmail.com', '..........@gmail.com',
          'A mail from you from Python',
          '<b>A mail from you from Python</b><br><br>' +
          'So happy to hear from you!')
```

Comment: Tentei colar o código, mas na hora que postou ficou um porcaria. Mas o código está no link do blog que eu citei no post.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.